Crystal Report - Formula for converting number to Spanish
I am working on a crystal report which I need to spell out the amount in Spanish. Was trying to get help from chatGPT but are not able to figure out how to fix the formula. Can someone give me some advise?
Dim result As String
Dim n As Number
n = {DealMain.DealtAmount}

Dim units() As String
Dim teens() As String
Dim tens() As String
Dim hundreds() As String

units = Split(" ,uno,dos,tres,cuatro,cinco,seis,siete,ocho,nueve", ",")
teens = Split("diez,once,doce,trece,catorce,quince,dieciséis,diecisiete,dieciocho,diecinueve", ",")
tens = Split(" ,diez,veinte,treinta,cuarenta,cincuenta,sesenta,setenta,ochenta,noventa", ",")
hundreds = Split(" ,ciento,doscientos,trescientos,cuatrocientos,quinientos,seiscientos,setecientos,ochocientos,novecientos", ",")

Dim unit As Number
Dim ten As Number
Dim hundred As Number

Dim ProcessHelper As String
ProcessHelper = ""

' Split the number into billions, millions, thousands, and the remainder
Dim billions As Number
Dim millions As Number
Dim thousands As Number
Dim remainder As Number

billions = n \ 1000000000
millions = (n Mod 1000000000) \ 1000000
thousands = (n Mod 1000000) \ 1000
remainder = n Mod 1000

'billions
If billions > 0 Then
    ProcessHelper = ""
    hundred = billions \ 100
    ten = (billions Mod 100) \ 10
    unit = billions Mod 10

    If hundred > 0 Then
        If hundred = 1 And ten = 0 And unit = 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = "cien "
        Else
            ProcessHelper = hundreds(hundred) & " "
        End If
    End If

    If ten = 1 Then
        ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & teens(unit) & " "
    Else
        If ten > 1 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & tens(ten) & " "
        End If
        If unit > 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & units(unit) & " "
        End If
    End If

    result = result & ProcessHelper & "mil millones "
End If

'millions
If millions > 0 Then
    ProcessHelper = ""
    hundred = millions \ 100
    ten = (millions Mod 100) \ 10
    unit = millions Mod 10

    If hundred > 0 Then
        If hundred = 1 And ten = 0 And unit = 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = "cien "
        Else
            ProcessHelper = hundreds(hundred) & " "
        End If
    End If

    If ten = 1 Then
        ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & teens(unit) & " "
    Else
        If ten > 1 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & tens(ten) & " "
        End If
        If unit > 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & units(unit) & " "
        End If
    End If

    result = result & ProcessHelper & "millones "
End If

'thousands
If thousands > 0 Then
    ProcessHelper = ""
    hundred = thousands \ 100
    ten = (thousands Mod 100) \ 10
    unit = thousands Mod 10

    If hundred > 0 Then
        If hundred = 1 And ten = 0 And unit = 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = "cien "
        Else
            ProcessHelper = hundreds(hundred) & " "
        End If
    End If

    If ten = 1 Then
        ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & teens(unit) & " "
    Else
        If ten > 1 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & tens(ten) & " "
        End If
        If unit > 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & units(unit) & " "
        End If
    End If

    If thousands = 1 Then
        result = result & "mil "
    Else
        result = result & ProcessHelper & "mil "
    End If
End If

If remainder > 0 Then
    ProcessHelper = ""
    hundred = remainder \ 100
    ten = (remainder Mod 100) \ 10
    unit = remainder Mod 10

    If hundred > 0 Then
        If hundred = 1 And ten = 0 And unit = 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = "cien "
        Else
            ProcessHelper = hundreds(hundred) & " "
        End If
    End If

    If ten = 1 Then
        ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & teens(unit) & " "
    Else
        If ten > 1 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & tens(ten) & " "
        End If
        If unit > 0 Then
            ProcessHelper = ProcessHelper & units(unit) & " "
        End If
    End If

    result = result & ProcessHelper
End If

formula = Trim(result)

The formula is giving me incorrect result:
For the amount of 63 million, the formula gives me cincuenta y dos millones (52 mil)
For the amount of 240,786k, the formula gives me ciento treinta millones seiscientos sententa cinco mil (130,675,000)
Can you please help advising why the formula is really off?
